# How to remove a given symbol from a list?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to remove a given symbol from a list.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
(define member?
  (lambda (in-sym in-seq)
    (if (and (symbol? in-sym) (sequence? in-seq))
        (if (null? in-seq)
            '()
            (append 
             (if (equal? in-sym (car in-seq)) '() (list (car in-seq))) 
             (member? in-sym (cdr in-seq)))))))
```

It turns out that i remove all occurences of the given symbol although i want to remove only the first occurence. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: [Proper formatting](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style) helps more than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a built-in procedure for this, check if your interpreter provides [`remove`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._remove%29%29):

```
(remove 'b '(a b b c b))
=> '(a b c b)
```

Now, if you intend to implement the functionality yourself, I advice you to split the problem in two parts: one procedure that checks if the procedure can be executed (if `inSymbol` is a symbol and `inSeq` is a sequence), and the other, `remove-member` that performs the actual removal of data:

```
(define member?
 (lambda (inSym inSeq)
   (if (and (symbol? inSym) (sequence? inSeq)) ; can remove?
       (remove-member inSym inSeq)             ; then remove!
       'can-not-remove))) ; otherwise, present an error message

(define remove-member
  (lambda (inSym inSeq)
    (cond ((null? inSeq)
           '())
          ((equal? (car inSeq) inSym)
           (cdr inSeq))
          (else
           (cons (car inSeq)
                 (remove-member inSym (cdr inSeq)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you,  but i am new to functional programming and trying not to use built in functions to understand the logic. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @constructor check my updated answer, this is the correct way to implement the remove procedure

Comment: This is a good deal cleaner than my quick and dirty solution.

Comment: @constructor you're welcome! please notice that my solution is the preferred way to solve this, using `append` to build a new list it's a bad idea (it's slower), if possible you should always try to use `cons` as in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you append to `( member?  inSym (  cdr inSeq))` whether you found the symbol or not. What you want to do is this:

```
(define member?
  (lambda (inSym inSeq)
    (if (and (symbol? inSym) (sequence? inSeq))
        (if (null? inSeq) '()
          (if (equal? inSym (car inSeq)) (cdr inSeq)
            (append (list (car inSec)) (member?  inSym (cdr inSeq)))
            )
          )
      )
    )
  )
```

I.e. if you found the symbol, just return (cdr inSeq) instead because you are done.